# how to disable a button in an android app

Tags: android, button

in my app i have three buttons namely A,B and C. I want the buttons B and C to be disabled until button A is clicked. they should be ready to perform this function until button A is clicked how to do this.....

Comment: u may used invisible or gone ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    buttonB.setEnabled(false);
    buttonC.setEnabled(false);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v == buttonA)
    {
        buttonB.setEnabled(true);
        buttonC.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you should write this will creating your app

`myButton.setEnabled(false);`

and in the button click function you should enable it by doing this.

`myButton.setEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 1):

```
// assuming valid references to buttons
buttonB.setEnabled(false);
buttonC.setEnabled(false);

buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    buttonB.setEnabled(true);
    buttonC.setEnabled(true);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Enable the button

```
myButton.setEnabled(true);
```